# Мониторинг чего-то или мониторинг за чем-то?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сказать:
"мониторинг **процесса**" или "мониторинг **за процессом**"?
Мониторинг — это наблюдение. И как же все-таки правильно?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В словаре сочетаемости этого слова нет. Я слышала только первый вариант. Мне он кажется правильным и связывается у меня со значением "отслеживание результатов". Мониторинг, например, процесса обучения - это отслеживание результатов обучения. Т.е. наблюдение может предполагать фиксирование результатов, а может быть пассивным, а мониторинг обязательно предполагает фиксацию результатов.

Набрала в поисковике мониторинг за... Вариантов тьма-тьмущая. Например, мониторинг за 5 класс. Видимо, слово осваивается языком, приобретает новые значения. В данном примере мониторинг то же, что и контрольные работы. Мне этот вариант кажется неверным. Поживем - увидим,что скажут словари... А может, у кого-нибудь уже есть более подробная информация.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, "мониторинг" сродни "контролю" (частным случаем какового и является).
Поэтому допустимы оба варианта. А, возможно, еще и третий: "мониторинг над чем-то".
Хотя последнее - только в бытовом понимании "мониторинга".
В специализированной литературе я бы предпочел "мониторинг чего-то" (как и "контроль").

Answer (score -1):

Слово *мониторинг* управляет родительным падежом. Правильно — мониторинг ч.-л. (цен, например).